# Unable to increment in code properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    takeHiResShot = Input.GetKeyDown("k");
    resWidth = 256;
    resHeight = 256;

    if (takeHiResShot)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {

            Vector3 buffer_x = new Vector3((int)rift.transform.eulerAngles.x + 1, (int)rift.transform.eulerAngles.y, (int)rift.transform.eulerAngles.z);
            rift.transform.eulerAngles = buffer_x;

            int y_buf = 160;
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            {
                Vector3 buffer_y = new Vector3((int)rift.transform.eulerAngles.x, (int)rift.transform.eulerAngles.y + 1, (int)rift.transform.eulerAngles.z);
                rift.transform.eulerAngles = buffer_y;

                Debug.Log(string.Format("i: {0}, j: {1}, eulerangles: {2}", i, j, rift.transform.eulerAngles));

                RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
                camera.targetTexture = rt;
                Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
                camera.Render();
                RenderTexture.active = rt;
                screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
                camera.targetTexture = null;
                RenderTexture.active = null; // JC: added to avoid errors
                Destroy(rt);
                byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
                string filename = ScreenShotName(rift.transform.eulerAngles, max_x, max_y);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
                takeHiResShot = false;
            }

            Vector3 buffer_reset = new Vector3((int)rift.transform.eulerAngles.x, y_buf, (int)rift.transform.eulerAngles.z);
            rift.transform.eulerAngles = buffer_reset;
        }

    }
}
```

I need to take photograph of a 3d object `rift` from different x and y euler angles. My Code works(for the most part) with initializing x=-20 and y=-5 and adding 1. But the code gets stuck at x=-16 and doesn't get any pictures beyond that. I am not understanding my bug at all and have been scratching my head for >3 hrs. How can I correct this?

Logs, if I dont make much sense:

```
i: 1, j: 0, eulerangles: (342.0, 161.0, 0.0)
i: 1, j: 1, eulerangles: (342.0, 162.0, 0.0)
i: 1, j: 2, eulerangles: (342.0, 163.0, 0.0)
i: 1, j: 3, eulerangles: (342.0, 164.0, 0.0)
i: 1, j: 4, eulerangles: (342.0, 165.0, 0.0)
i: 2, j: 0, eulerangles: (343.0, 161.0, 0.0)
i: 2, j: 1, eulerangles: (343.0, 162.0, 0.0)
i: 2, j: 2, eulerangles: (343.0, 163.0, 0.0)
i: 2, j: 3, eulerangles: (343.0, 164.0, 0.0)
i: 2, j: 4, eulerangles: (343.0, 165.0, 0.0)
i: 3, j: 0, eulerangles: (344.0, 161.0, 0.0)
i: 3, j: 1, eulerangles: (344.0, 162.0, 0.0)
i: 3, j: 2, eulerangles: (344.0, 163.0, 0.0)
i: 3, j: 3, eulerangles: (344.0, 164.0, 0.0)
i: 3, j: 4, eulerangles: (344.0, 165.0, 0.0)
i: 4, j: 0, eulerangles: (344.0, 161.0, 0.0)
i: 4, j: 1, eulerangles: (344.0, 162.0, 0.0)
i: 4, j: 2, eulerangles: (344.0, 163.0, 0.0)
```

Assuming that it might be a problem for eulerangles to be incremented the way I am doing, I tried using `rift.transform.Rotate` with `Vector3(1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)` for x axis rotation(outer loop) and `Vector3(0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F)` for y axis rotation(inner loop). It also gets stuck at x_angle = 9. I am not sure why rotation is getting stuck.

Logs(I am not incrementing inner loop in this version, so 175.0 values are intentional) :

```
i: 7, j: 4, eulerangles: (8.0, 175.0, 0.0)
i: 8, j: 0, eulerangles: (9.0, 175.0, 0.0)
i: 8, j: 1, eulerangles: (9.0, 175.0, 0.0)
i: 8, j: 2, eulerangles: (9.0, 175.0, 0.0)
i: 8, j: 3, eulerangles: (9.0, 175.0, 0.0)
i: 8, j: 4, eulerangles: (9.0, 175.0, 0.0)
i: 9, j: 0, eulerangles: (9.0, 175.0, 0.0)
i: 9, j: 1, eulerangles: (9.0, 175.0, 0.0)
i: 9, j: 2, eulerangles: (9.0, 175.0, 0.0)
i: 9, j: 3, eulerangles: (9.0, 175.0, 0.0)
i: 9, j: 4, eulerangles: (9.0, 175.0, 0.0)
i: 10, j: 0, eulerangles: (9.0, 175.0, 0.0)
```

`i` stopped incrementing again at i=9 and continues with same value till i=19(end of loop).

New Code :

```
Vector3 GenerateXBuffer(Vector3 eulerAngles)
{
    Vector3 x_buffer;
    x_buffer = new Vector3((int)eulerAngles.x + 2, (int)eulerAngles.y, (int)eulerAngles.z);
    return x_buffer;
}

Vector3 GenerateYBuffer(Vector3 eulerAngles)
{
    Vector3 y_buffer;
    y_buffer = new Vector3((int)eulerAngles.x, (int)eulerAngles.y + 2, (int)eulerAngles.z);
    return y_buffer;
}

void StartTakingPictures()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        rift.transform.eulerAngles = GenerateXBuffer(rift.transform.eulerAngles);
        int y_buf = 175;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            rift.transform.eulerAngles = GenerateYBuffer(rift.transform.eulerAngles);

            Debug.Log(string.Format("i: {0}, j: {1}, eulerangles: {2}", i, j, rift.transform.eulerAngles));

            RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
            camera.targetTexture = rt;
            Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            camera.Render();
            RenderTexture.active = rt;
            screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
            camera.targetTexture = null;
            RenderTexture.active = null; // JC: added to avoid errors
            Destroy(rt);
            byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
            string filename = ScreenShotName(rift.transform.eulerAngles, max_x, max_y);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
            takeHiResShot = false;
        }

        Vector3 buffer_reset = new Vector3((int)rift.transform.eulerAngles.x, y_buf, (int)rift.transform.eulerAngles.z);
        rift.transform.eulerAngles = buffer_reset;
    }
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    takeHiResShot = Input.GetKeyDown("k");
    resWidth = 256;
    resHeight = 256;

    if (takeHiResShot)
    {
        StartTakingPictures();
    }
}
```

Hi @Aizen, as you suggested, I took the calculation out of the update loop and it did help. I am now getting 82 images (was getting 56 before), although I should be getting a 100. Can you see anymore errors that might be causing problems?

Comment: Try commenting out the codes within your second for loop, and put them back one by one. Leave the Debug.Log line.

Comment: It works if I increment in the outer loop (ie, x values) by 2 instead of 1. Can you suggest why that would be ?

Comment: look at your output  i: 4, j: 0, your angles are 344, 161, It should be 345, 161.

Comment: Yes that is the problem.

Comment: Trying to do a forloop on any Update function that needs precise calculation is dangerous, have you tried making a seperate Function and call it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems here:

1. You are manipulating rotations **dangerously** (see the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html));
2. You are manipulating floating points numbers **dangerously** (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit-numeric-conversions-table)).

Unity stores and manipulates all rotations internally as [Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation), not as [Euler Angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles), and they had their [reasons](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) to do so. Hence, `Transform.rotation` is a field of type `Quaternion`. Quaternions are less intuitive for people to use so in most situations you want to apply rotations as separate Euler components. That's why they added properties like `Transform.eulerAngles`, that returns and takes a `Vector3`.

However, when you set this property, like `rift.transform.eulerAngles = buffer_x;` there is no `Vector3` backing field in the `Transform` class storing the same values you passed. Instead, It is converted to `Quaternion` and stored in the backing field of `Transform.rotation`. Similarly, when you get this property, its internal `Quaternion` value is converted into a `Vector3` and returned. As a consquence of those 2 internal operations, the value you *get back* from this property **may not** be the same value as you *passed* to it.

I suggest you to do this experiment. Try this snippet inside any reachable part of your Component script:

```
for (float i = 0f; i <= 360f; i++)
{
  rift.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(i, 0, 0);
  Debug.Log(i.ToString("R") + " -> " + rift.transform.eulerAngles.x.ToString("R"));
}
```

And take a look at the log:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 3
4 -> 4
5 -> 5.00000048
6 -> 6
7 -> 7.00000143
8 -> 8
9 -> 9.000001
10 -> 9.999999
11 -> 11
12 -> 12
13 -> 13.000001
14 -> 14
15 -> 15.0000019
16 -> 16.0000038
17 -> 17
18 -> 18.0000019
19 -> 18.9999981
20 -> 20.0000038
21 -> 21
22 -> 22.0000038
23 -> 22.9999981
24 -> 24.0000019
25 -> 25
26 -> 25.9999981
27 -> 27
28 -> 28
29 -> 29
30 -> 30.0000038
31 -> 31.0000019
32 -> 32
33 -> 33
34 -> 34
35 -> 34.9999962
36 -> 36.0000038
37 -> 36.9999962
38 -> 37.9999962
39 -> 39.0000038
40 -> 40.0000076
41 -> 41.0000038
42 -> 42.0000038
43 -> 43.0000038
44 -> 43.9999962
45 -> 45.0000038
46 -> 46
47 -> 47.0000038
48 -> 48
49 -> 49.0000038
50 -> 50.00001
51 -> 51
52 -> 52.0000038
53 -> 52.9999962
54 -> 54.0000038
55 -> 55.0000076
56 -> 56.00001
57 -> 57.0000038
58 -> 58
59 -> 59
60 -> 60.0000038
61 -> 61.0000038
62 -> 61.9999962
63 -> 62.9999924
64 -> 64
65 -> 65
66 -> 66.00001
67 -> 67
68 -> 68.00001
69 -> 69.00001
70 -> 70.0000153
71 -> 71.00001
72 -> 72
73 -> 73.00001
74 -> 74
75 -> 75
76 -> 76.0000153
77 -> 77.0000153
78 -> 78.00002
79 -> 79
80 -> 80.00003
81 -> 80.9999847
82 -> 82.0000153
83 -> 83.00002
84 -> 84.0000153
85 -> 85.00005
86 -> 86.00002
87 -> 87.00004
88 -> 88.00002
89 -> 89.00005
90 -> 90
91 -> 89.00005
92 -> 88.00002
93 -> 87.00004
94 -> 86.00002
95 -> 85.00001
96 -> 84.0000153
97 -> 83.00002
98 -> 81.99998
99 -> 80.9999847
100 -> 80.0000153
101 -> 79
102 -> 78.00001
103 -> 77.0000153
104 -> 76
105 -> 75
106 -> 74.0000153
107 -> 73.0000153
108 -> 72.0000153
109 -> 71.00001
110 -> 70.0000153
111 -> 69.00001
112 -> 68.0000153
113 -> 67
114 -> 66.00001
115 -> 64.99999
116 -> 64
117 -> 63.00001
118 -> 61.9999962
119 -> 61.0000038
120 -> 60.0000038
121 -> 59
122 -> 58.0000076
123 -> 57.0000038
124 -> 56.0000038
125 -> 55.0000038
126 -> 54.0000076
127 -> 53.0000038
128 -> 52.0000038
129 -> 51.0000076
130 -> 50
131 -> 49.0000076
132 -> 48
133 -> 47.0000038
134 -> 46.00001
135 -> 45.0000038
136 -> 44.0000076
137 -> 43.0000038
138 -> 42
139 -> 40.9999962
140 -> 40.0000038
141 -> 39.0000076
142 -> 37.9999962
143 -> 37.0000076
144 -> 36
145 -> 35
146 -> 34.0000076
147 -> 32.9999962
148 -> 32.0000038
149 -> 31.0000019
150 -> 30.0000038
151 -> 28.9999924
152 -> 28
153 -> 27.0000076
154 -> 25.9999981
155 -> 25.0000038
156 -> 23.9999962
157 -> 23
158 -> 22.0000076
159 -> 21
160 -> 20.0000076
161 -> 18.9999943
162 -> 18.0000038
163 -> 17.0000076
164 -> 16.0000038
165 -> 15.00001
166 -> 13.999999
167 -> 13.0000038
168 -> 11.9999952
169 -> 11.000001
170 -> 10.0000076
171 -> 8.999999
172 -> 8.000005
173 -> 6.999997
174 -> 6.000002
175 -> 5.000008
176 -> 4
177 -> 3.00000525
178 -> 1.9999975
179 -> 1.000003
180 -> -5.008956E-06
181 -> 359
182 -> 358
183 -> 357
184 -> 356
185 -> 355
186 -> 354
187 -> 353
188 -> 352
189 -> 351
190 -> 350
191 -> 349
192 -> 348
193 -> 347
194 -> 346
195 -> 345
196 -> 344
197 -> 343
198 -> 342
199 -> 341
200 -> 340
201 -> 339
202 -> 338
203 -> 337
204 -> 336
205 -> 335
206 -> 334
207 -> 333
208 -> 332
209 -> 331
210 -> 330
211 -> 329
212 -> 328
213 -> 327
214 -> 326
215 -> 325
216 -> 324
217 -> 323
218 -> 322
219 -> 321
220 -> 320
221 -> 319
222 -> 318
223 -> 317
224 -> 316
225 -> 315
226 -> 314
227 -> 313
228 -> 312
229 -> 311
230 -> 310
231 -> 309
232 -> 308
233 -> 307
234 -> 306
235 -> 305
236 -> 304
237 -> 303
238 -> 302
239 -> 301
240 -> 300
241 -> 299
242 -> 298
243 -> 297
244 -> 296
245 -> 295
246 -> 294
247 -> 293
248 -> 292
249 -> 290.999969
250 -> 290
251 -> 289
252 -> 288
253 -> 287
254 -> 285.999969
255 -> 285
256 -> 284
257 -> 283
258 -> 282
259 -> 280.999969
260 -> 280
261 -> 279
262 -> 277.999969
263 -> 277.000031
264 -> 275.999939
265 -> 275
266 -> 273.999939
267 -> 272.999878
268 -> 271.999969
269 -> 270.999939
270 -> 270
271 -> 270.999939
272 -> 271.999969
273 -> 273.000031
274 -> 273.999969
275 -> 275
276 -> 276
277 -> 276.999969
278 -> 278
279 -> 279
280 -> 280
281 -> 281
282 -> 282
283 -> 283
284 -> 284
285 -> 285
286 -> 285.999969
287 -> 287
288 -> 288
289 -> 289
290 -> 290
291 -> 290.999969
292 -> 292
293 -> 293
294 -> 294
295 -> 295
296 -> 296
297 -> 297
298 -> 298
299 -> 299
300 -> 300
301 -> 301
302 -> 302
303 -> 303
304 -> 304
305 -> 305
306 -> 305.999969
307 -> 307
308 -> 308
309 -> 309
310 -> 310
311 -> 311
312 -> 312
313 -> 313
314 -> 314
315 -> 315
316 -> 316
317 -> 317
318 -> 318
319 -> 319
320 -> 320
321 -> 320.999969
322 -> 322
323 -> 323
324 -> 324
325 -> 325
326 -> 326
327 -> 327
328 -> 328
329 -> 329
330 -> 330
331 -> 331
332 -> 332
333 -> 333
334 -> 334
335 -> 335
336 -> 336
337 -> 337
338 -> 338
339 -> 339
340 -> 340
341 -> 341
342 -> 342
343 -> 343
344 -> 344
345 -> 344.999969
346 -> 346
347 -> 347
348 -> 348
349 -> 349
350 -> 349.999969
351 -> 351
352 -> 352
353 -> 353
354 -> 354
355 -> 354.999969
356 -> 356
357 -> 357
358 -> 358
359 -> 359
360 -> 1.00179122E-05
```

Now, look for the output corresponding to `i = 345f` and you'll see `344.999969`. Have you figured it out, now? Well, in your code, in the `i = 3` iteration, you set `rift.transform.eulerAngles` with the value `345f` as the `x` component. Then, in the next iteration you do `(int)rift.transform.eulerAngles.x`. That will resolve to `(int)344.999969`, that is `344` **again**, and not `345`!! (Remember that explicit conversion from `float` to `int` just removes the fractionary part, no rounding). It keeps repeating this result from this point onward, that's why your increment stucks.

That's one of the reasons that Unity considers it a mistaken approach and says:

> the mistake here is that we are reading, modifying then writing the Euler
>   values from a quaternion. Because these values calculated from a Quaternion,
>   each new rotation may return very different Euler angles, which may suffer from gimbal lock.

Now is an appropriate moment to mention [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock). I will not dive into this, but I very recommend the reading. Moreover, take a look at the log between `i = 90f` and `i = 270f` to see the danger of what you are doing.

---

By the way... why are you ever converting the Euler components to `int` at all? I can't see why is it necessary there. You can just use the float values and increment them all the way. You could even use a float iteration variable in the do loop, just like in my snippet before.

Avoid the pratice of assuming a whole-number representation from a floating point value. Applying simple operations on a float can break this assumption, as well as using high numbers. Look this:

```
int a = 1000;
float x = Mathf.Sqrt(a) * Mathf.Sqrt(a);
Debug.Log("a: " + a + "; x: " + x.ToString("R") + " -> (int)x: " + (int)x);
// a: 1000; x: 999.999939 -> (int)x: 999

a = 100000001;
x = a;
Debug.Log("a: " + a + "; x: " + x.ToString("R") + " -> (int)x: " + (int)x);
// a: 100000001; x: 1E+08 -> (int)x: 100000000
```

---

If you really, *really* need to convert the angles to int, I suggest you this approach:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
  // (...)
  takeHiResShot = Input.GetKeyDown("k");
  if (takeHiResShot)
  {
    Vector3 startAngles = rift.transform.eulerAngles;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = 1; j <= 5; ++j)
      {
        //Setting transform.rotation is safer than setting transform.eulerAngles
        rift.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler((int)startAngles.x + i, (int)startAngles.y + j, (int)startAngles.z);
        Debug.Log(string.Format("i: {0}, j: {1}, eulerangles: {2}", i, j, rift.transform.eulerAngles));
        // (...)
      }
      //It is safe here because you didn't manipulate the value,
      //but Quaternion.Euler is still more advisable
      rift.transform.eulerAngles = startAngles;
    }
  }
}
```